# How to reload a partial View with refreshed Model from Index

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to reload my Partial View `_Home` when I close my dropdown.  Currently I can get that dropdown value to call another method and do the logic that will change the model then send the model back to the index.  However, I cannot get my `_Home` Partial View to reload and actually take in this new model.  I cannot seem to be able to actually call the `public ActionResult _Home(Model model)` method.  I am wondering how to pass in this new model and refresh the partial view.

I have tried to pass in the model to the partial view but this seems to have no effect, having no model being passed in does not change anything either.  I have seen a few examples online of how to refresh partial views but none of them pass in any parameters.

JavaScript

```
function OnClose() {
    var chart = $("#safetyIncident-chart").data("kendoChart");
    var chart2 = $("#qualityError-chart").data("kendoChart");
    chart.dataSource.read();
    chart2.dataSource.read();

    var selectProductionLine = $("#productionLine-dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateView", "Home")', //Updates model and then calls Index
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "selectProductionLine": JSON.stringify(selectProductionLine) }, //Passes in DropDownValue correctly
        success: function (data) {
            $("#partial").html(result);
            $("#Dashboard").load("/Home/_Home"); //Trying to reload the partial view
        }

    });
}
```

View

```
<div id="Dashboard">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/_Home.cshtml")
</div>
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DisplayViewModel dvm = (DisplayViewModel)TempData["dvm"];
    if(dvm != null)
    {
        return View(dvm);
    }
        //Initializes new dvm if previous was null
        return View(dvm);
    }
```

I am trying to refresh my partial view once DropDown closes and the ViewModel is refreshed.

**EDIT:**
UpdateView method in Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateView(string selectProductionLine)
{
    if(selectProductionLine == null)
    {
        selectProductionLine = _productionLineService.Collection().FirstOrDefault().Id;
    }

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(selectProductionLine, typeof(string));

    DisplayViewModel dvm = new DisplayViewModel();
    ProductionLine pl = _productionLineService.Find(jsondata);
    dvm.ProdLine = new ProductionLineViewModel
    {
        Id = pl.Id,
        CreatedAt = pl.CreatedAt,
        Name = pl.Name,
        ActiveLine = pl.ActiveLine,
        ComputerName = pl.ComputerName,
        UPE = pl.UPE
    };
    TempData["dvm"] = dvm;
    return Index();
    //PartialView("~/Home/_Home.cshtml", dvm);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't       $("#partial").html(result);     be       $("#partial").html(data); ?

Comment: So I changed  ```$("#Dashboard").html(data);``` and it still does not appear to refresh the partial.  I am still learning JS and this is code that I have received from other questions on stack overflow so I am not 100% sure how they work.

Comment: Can you try using  $("#Dashboard").text(data); instead of load("/Home/_Home"); ? If that is not working, use debug and check if you receive any data.

Comment: So I did that and I am getting an exception on the UpdateView method.  However, I am still able to call the index and pass in a new dvm.